# Blur Material UI Select component on the onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

By default MaterialUI's Select component leaves itself focused after selecting an option. This behaviour can be seen in all their examples in their [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/)

I would like the element to blur once something is selected. Here is what my code currently looks like:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('')

    const selectElement = useRef(null);

  return (
        <Select
            native
            ref={selectElement}
            value={selectedValue}
            onChange={(evt) => {
                setSelectedValue(evt.target.value)

                // Attempt at blurring the element upon selection using the useRef:
                selectElement.current.blur(); // Nothing happens

                // Attempt at blurring the element upon selection using activeElement:
                document.activeElement.blur(); // Get Error: "Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'Element'."
            }}
        >
            <option value='option 1'>Option 1</option>
            <option value='option 2'>Option 2</option>
            <option value='option 3'>Option 3</option>
        </Select>
  );
};
```

As you can see in the code, I've tried to do this with two different methods I've found:

- Through `useRef()`: this does nothing, no errors or anything, but does not blur my element
- Through the `document.activeElement`: this gives me an error, apparently property `blur` does not exist on type element.

What is the proper method of blurring my Select component upon selecting an option?

Comment: You need to defer the blur effect. The focused element is not on the screen after selecting.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to blur the option, but I think you want to blur the select itself. Try `selectElement.blur();` or `evt.target.blur();`

Comment: Note the ref is being forwarded to the root element (a wrapper div), not the `select`, which is why the that solution does nothing.

Comment: The error you're seeing looks TypeScript-related, but you haven't included any typing in your question/code.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to blur the Select. This seems like a horrible thing to do from an accessibility standpoint.

Comment: I have added  this in onChange event

 setTimeout(() => {
                document.activeElement.blur()
            }) 

and it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing some of the comments into an answer:

As @2pha suggests, using `evt.target.blur()` is probably the way to go:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <Select
      native
      value={selectedValue}
      onChange={(evt) => {
        setSelectedValue(evt.target.value);

        console.log(document.activeElement); // <select>
        evt.target.blur();
        console.log(document.activeElement); // <body>
      }}>
      <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option 3">Option 3</option>
    </Select>
  );
};
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-night-oqlgr

The ref isn't working because [it's being forwarded to the root element](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) (a `div`) not the `select` element.

The error you're seeing related to `document.activeElement` looks TypeScript-related. You're seeing it because `document.activeElement` is generically typed as `Element`, which doesn't have a `blur` method. You'd need to specify the `HTMLSelectElement` type, but it doesn't seem worth pursuing that route since it's more straightforward to just use `evt.target`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for the native Select components, but I do need to use this for non-native ones as well, which for whatever does not have the `blur` function (`evt.target` only has `name` and `value` attributes). How could I do it for this case?

Comment: I've forked your sandbox example to add the non-native select component: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-archimedes-3qcnt

Comment: @theJuls The difficulty with the non-native select is one of timing. `onChange` is triggered by clicking a `MenuItem` and at the time of `onChange` the `MenuItem` still has focus. After the Menu/Select is closed, the Select's `div` receives focus. If you call `document.activeElement.blur()` within a `setTimeout` callback, it works as desired: https://codesandbox.io/s/non-native-select-blur-jjiu8.

Answer (score 4):

inspired by @ericgio and @Ryan Cogswell answers there's another way to tackle this. For non-native elements, we can assign a `setTimeout` function to the `onClose` which will blur the element after selecting the option from menu.

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Select
          style={{ width: '200px' }}
          native
          value={selectedValue}
          onChange={(evt) => {
            setSelectedValue(evt.target.value);
            evt.target.blur();
          }}>
          <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="option 3">Option 3</option>
        </Select>
      </div>
      <FormControl style={{ width: '200px' }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          onClose={() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              document.activeElement.blur();
            }, 0);
          }}
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Sandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-microservice-xufqc